# Detecting and dropping outliers from a dataset

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

Feeling a bit frustrated with this exercise I have to complete. I'm fairly new to python but have some experience with Matlab, although it is entirely different.

I am required to detect all the outliers in the dataset and remove them. I have successfully located the outliers by both IQR and Z score and am ending up with a list of true and false. This is fine, except I don't know how to access the specific row that says False to locate the exact row of the outlying data in order to remove it from the dataset. I've been searching the web and stack overflow for hours and I am just completely stuck on this. any help is appreciated.

error:

IndexingError: Unalignable boolean Series provided as indexer (index of the boolean Series and of the indexed object do not match).[enter image description here][1]

![1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YGK04.png

Comment: Can you provide code and error?

Comment: look up "numpy boolean indexing"

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
df = data.iloc[((data['mpg'] >= q1-limit)| (data['mpg'] >= q3+limit)).index, :].reset_index(inplace = True)
```

Comment: IndexingError: Unalignable boolean Series provided as indexer (index of the boolean Series and of the indexed object do not match) is the error I get

Comment: Can you try again?

Comment: Looks like you have reassigned a new dataframe to the data variable and it is not in the original form. Please confirm that once. I have also made some edit to the solution.

Comment: KeyError: "None of [Int64Index([  1,   2,   3,   4,   5,   6,   7,   8,   9,  10,\n            ...\n            386, 387, 388, 389, 390, 391, 392, 393, 394, 395],\n           dtype='int64', length=393)] are in the [columns]" i get that error from your new code. the dataframe for the data variable is unchanged

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are a bunch of ways to trim down data or in your case, get rid of outliers.  Here are 2 standard approaches.  The first one uses list comprehensions, which are a core feature of python and are pretty straightforward.  Simple web search can be used to see many examples, but in your case, it is good for filtering with a conditional statement.  This can be done on basic python lists.

The second example, with `data2` uses a feature of the `numpy` library which it appears you might be using, which is conditional indexing.  You can basically put the condition as an index and go with it.

```
In [5]: data                                                                                              
Out[5]: [1, 5, 66, 2, 33, 400, 26, 201]

In [6]: mean = sum(data)/len(data)                                                                        

In [7]: data_trimmed = [t for t in data if t <= mean]                                                     

In [8]: data_trimmed                                                                                      
Out[8]: [1, 5, 66, 2, 33, 26]

In [9]: import numpy as np                                                                                

In [10]: data2 = np.array(data)                                                                           

In [11]: data2                                                                                            
Out[11]: array([  1,   5,  66,   2,  33, 400,  26, 201])

In [12]: data2_trimmed = data2[data2 <= mean]                                                             

In [13]: data2_trimmed                                                                                    
Out[13]: array([ 1,  5, 66,  2, 33, 26])
```